# Github: commit from unrelated branch appearing in pull request

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've read the docs, I've looked at similar questions and I must still be overlooking something extremely simple.

Here's what I want to accomplish:

1. Fork a repo.
2. Create branch `issue1`, commit a fix for issue #1, push.
3. Create a pull request from `issue1`, only with the fix for issue #1.
4. Create branch `issue2`, commit a fix for issue #2, push.
5. Create a pull request from `issue2`, **only with the fix for issue #2.**

Here's what I did:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master

git checkout -b issue1
echo "123" > issue1.txt && git add issue1.txt
git commit -m "issue1 fix"
git push origin issue1 

git checkout -b issue2
echo "123" > issue2.txt && git add issue2.txt
git commit -m "issue2 fix"
git push origin issue2
```

I made pull requests from both branches ([PR 1](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/pull/4631) and [PR 2](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/pull/4632)), **and the one from `issue2` has both commits (from both branches)**. How can I avoid this when working on multiple issues/branches at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created the `issue2` branch, you branched off `issue1` to create it.  Unless you provide a second argument to `git branch` (or `git checkout -b` in your case) to indicate the starting branch, the created branch will be based off the current branch - which in your case is `issue1`.

To fix your problem, either switch back to `master` before creating `issue2`, or execute `git checkout -b issue2 master`.

Comment: Yup, overlooking something extremely simple. Thanks!